# Conditional Filtering with if in elasticsearch

Tags: if-statement, elasticsearch, logstash

I have the following filter.conf file in my logstash configuration:

```
filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "node" => "%{[@metadata][rabbitmq_headers][node]}"
            "connection" => "%{[@metadata][rabbitmq_headers][connection]}"
            "vhost" => "%{[@metadata][rabbitmq_headers][vhost]}"
            "user" => "%{[@metadata][rabbitmq_headers][user]}"
            "channel" => "%{[@metadata][rabbitmq_headers][channel]}"
            "exchange" => "%{[@metadata][rabbitmq_headers][exchange_name]}"
            "routing_keys" => "%{[@metadata][rabbitmq_headers][routing_keys]}"
            "routed_queues" => "%{[@metadata][rabbitmq_headers][routed_queues]}"
            "routing-key" => "%{[@metadata][rabbitmq_properties][routing-key]}"
        }
    }
    if [exchange] == "OUTGOING.E.TOPIC" {
      mutate { add_field => "status" => "Outgoing message" }
    } else if [exchange] == "INCOMING.E.TOPIC" {
      mutate { add_field => "status" => "Incoming message" }
    } else {
      mutate { add_field => "status" => "Unknown" }
    }
}
```

But, when I try to run logstash I get:

```
Cannot create pipeline {:reason=>"Expected one of #, {, \", ', }
```

In the if condition (If I remove it, it works). What am I doing wrong with the if condition?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing brackets around the `"status" => "Outgoing message"`

It would look like this:

```
if [exchange] == "OUTGOING.E.TOPIC" {
  mutate { 
    add_field => {
      "status" => "Outgoing message"
    } 
  }
} else if [exchange] == "INCOMING.E.TOPIC" {
  mutate { add_field => {"status" => "Incoming message"} } 
} else {
  mutate { add_field => {"status" => "Unknown"} }
}
```

You can see the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field).